# How to leave the body of a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have some list and I do `list.ForEach( l => { ... something ...})`. Now, on certain condition I need to stop iterating over the list, but `break` doesn't work - I get  "`Control cannot leave the body of an anonymous method or lambda expression`" compilation error.

Any idea how to overcome that restriction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `break` alone won't work here because the lambda executes in a different method than the for loop.  A `break` statement is only useful for breaking out of constructs local to the current function.

In order to support a break style leave you'd need to add an overload of `ForEach` where the delegate can specify via a return value that loop execution should break.  For example

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> func) {
  foreach (var cur in enumerable) {
    if (!func(cur)) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now a consumer of this `ForEach` method can specify a `break` by returning `false` from the provided callback

```
myCollection.ForEach(current => {
  if (someCondition) {
    // Need to break
    return false;
  }
  // Keep going
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A lambda expression works just like a method.
It can `return` whenever you want.

However, `List.ForEach` does not offer any way to prematurely stop the iteration.
If you need to `break`, you just use a normal `foreach` loop.

Comment: And what would you do in leu of `continue` if you need to conditionally skip an iteration - it doesn't work either.

Comment: You'd have the lambda return a boolean inside your loop, and, if it returned false, you'd break.

Comment: *"I need to stop iterating over the list, but break doesn't work"* - this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Porges - you are right, I just checked and return equals to continue in this case. Still trying to figure out how to leave the loop conditionally.

Comment: Yup, I see that now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop iteration from within a `ForEach` lambda since you do not have control of the outer loop that is calling the lambda. At that point why don't you use a regular `foreach` loop and a `break` statement - that would be much more readable for this case.

Comment: The only reason I use lambda is because I like using lambda, and that's the only reason it was added to C# - convenience. You are right - if it doesn't work for a certain case I will use foreach or whatever is applicable; I am just curious if there is a way to still use it. That's it, just a curious mind :)